# I can't navigate in the 3D view of modo 701 in Ubuntu 13.04. Is the OS overriding the shortcuts somehow? How can I fix it?

Tags: shortcut-keys, shortcuts, navigation

I installed [Luxology modo 701](http://www.luxology.com/modo/) on my Ubuntu 13.04 but if I try to navigate the 3D via the usual key combinations **<kbd>ALT</kbd>+Left/Middle/Right Click and Drag** nothing happens in the viewport.

**<kbd>ALT</kbd>+Right Click** only gives me Ubuntu's **Minimize/Unmaximize/Move/Resize/Always On Top/Close** menu and **<kbd>ALT</kbd>+Left Click and Drag** unmaximises the window and drags it around.

So I assume I need to somehow get Ubuntu to not override modo's shortcuts.

Any idea how I do that? Thanks in advance for any help!

Answer (score 1):

For the moment use <kbd>alt</kbd>+<kbd>windows</kbd>. I'm searching for this also...

[Found this](http://blenderartists.org/forum/showthread.php?280952-Help!-I-broke-Ubuntu-by-disabling-alt-key-mouse-modifier) but it doesn't work on Ubuntu 12.04...

**Edit**: Found it!

Open a terminal and run this command:

```
gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.wm.preferences mouse-button-modifier "<Super>"
```